# Define text blocks on a static page

Tags: floats, positioning, line-breaking

I am looking for a way to write own static pages with latex. For this I am mixing environments and commands. Right now I have a very easy Title page which is not working out really good.

It should look like this:

```
               - LOGO -
               DA TITLE

LEFT DATE                 RIGHT AUTHOR
```

Where the title is bigger and centered and the date and the author are a little bit smaller but left / right floating.

I am able to position the blocks, but with a few problems that show me, I am using the wrong approach.

For example the title is not line breaking if too long and neither left nor right is floating.

```
\newcommand{\MyTitlePage}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
        \node[anchor=north, text=black, font=\small, inner ysep=0.5cm, inner xsep=2cm] at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[width=12cm]{logo.png}};
        \node[anchor=north, text=black, font=\small, inner ysep=0.5cm, inner xsep=2cm] at ($(current page.center) + (0cm,-4cm)$) {\fontsize{24}{28}\MontserratBold \centering{\varDocumentTitle }};
        \node[anchor=north, text=black, font=\small, inner ysep=0.5cm, inner xsep=2cm] at ($(current page.west) + (+3cm,-8cm)$) {\fontsize{14}{18}\MontserratBold \raggedleft \varDate };
        \node[anchor=north, text=black, font=\small, inner ysep=0.5cm, inner xsep=2cm] at ($(current page.east) + (-3cm,-8cm)$) {\fontsize{14}{18}\MontserratBold \raggedright{\varAuthor} };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \pagebreak

}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: For line breaking within tikz nodes you should use `align=left`, `align=justify` or `align=right` as an option of the corresponding node.

Comment: @BastianBringenberg please revert if any problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title page

[image]

and the second page

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\MyTitlePage}{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
        \node[] 
            at ($(current page.north)+(0cm, -4cm)$) {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}};
        \node[] 
            at ($(current page.center) + (0cm,0cm)$) {\Huge Title };
        \node[] 
            at ($(current page.west) + (+3cm,-8cm)$) {\Large Date };
        \node[] 
            at ($(current page.east) + (-3cm,-8cm)$) {\Large Author};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
}
\MyTitlePage
Dear
\end{document}
```

**For dividing the long title**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\MyTitlePage}{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
        \node[] 
            at ($(current page.north)+(0cm, -4cm)$) {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}};
        \node[text width=4cm, align=center] 
            at ($(current page.center) + (0cm,0cm)$) {\Huge {A Very Long Title} };
        \node[] 
            at ($(current page.west) + (+3cm,-8cm)$) {\Large Date };
        \node[] 
            at ($(current page.east) + (-3cm,-8cm)$) {\Large Author};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
}
\MyTitlePage
Dear
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for, I was not aware, that I can add a "width" attribute on a node!

Comment: @BastianBringenberg would you consider upvoting the answer

Comment: Of couse! Sorry! Thought that I only verify it works and do no upvotes to not do duplicates^^ =).